# PHP - How can I determine the numeric sequential value of a character in the english alphabet?

Tags: php, converters, typeconverter

Without using a loop, is there a way (function) to convert, for example, the letter "c" to its numeric sequence in the alphabet (3)?

I'm trying to take a literal string - `$var = "c"` and apply a function to it that returns `3`.

Are there any built-in PHP functions that do this?  I can't find any online and would rather avoid writing the function if necessary.

Anyone know of such a conversion function?

Comment: Pretty much common to all programming languages - `$var = ord(strtoupper('C')) - 64;`

Answer (score 0):

[Yup.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php)

```
$alphabet_position = ord(strtoupper($character)) - ord('A');
```

Comment: Note that this offsets from 0 (ie A = 0); so C = 2